# I am trying to connect Angular to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular, mongodb

I have a simple Angular app and it is running in Local Host 4200. How do I save the form values and store them in a MongoDB database?

Comment: Please can you share some code, have you created a REST API ?

Comment: You need to build a BackEnd, there are many tutorials to build MEAN (mongo-express-angular-nodejs) stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Angular is a web framework dedicated for the client-side, MongoDB is
  a NoSQL database, to save your data put into your angular app to your
  Database, you need a [server-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction) implementation like [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) or
  python, java, etc ..
- I recommend for you to use [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) as an API framework it can helps you to get started

Answer (score 1):

Angular is not supposed to connect directly to a DB in an real project, so there is not much of a point to practice doing so. You should have an server-side application or a mock to do so. If you are trying to build a front for studies you can use packages such as this one to begin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-api

It is of simple use and you can save data without configuring or installing a DB.